# Angular ng-view does not work in MVC partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ng-view

I am trying to load a partial view(_Test.cshtml) into my Index view of the Product controller.

However the partial view opens in a new page, I have searched a lot on here and google. But I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong? Any help is really appreciated!

**MVC Controller**

```
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Product/_Test.cshtml");
        }
//this returns the partial view

        public ActionResult TestData()
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            var db = new HotStuffPizzaContext();

            var result = (from p in db.Products
                          select p)
                          .Where(x => x.ProductID != 0)
                          .Select(a => new
                          {
                              ProductID = a.ProductID,
                              Description = a.Description
                          });
            return Json(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

//this is called by angular controller

**Angular script**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/Product', {
            templateUrl: '/Product/Index',
            controller: 'testCtrl'
        }).
    when('Product/Test', {
        templateUrl: '/Views/Product/_Test',
        controller: 'testCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix("!");

}]);

myApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('/Product/TestData').success(function (data) {
          $scope.products = data;
      });
  }]);
```

**Product/Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

## INDEX VIEW

```
<a href="Product/Test">Test</a>
<div ng-view="">

</div>
```

**Partial View**

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<body data-ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">

            <tr >
                <th>id</th>
                <th>description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="p in products">
                <td>{{p.ProductID}}</td>
                <td>{{p.Description}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="../../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/App/app.js"></script>
```

I also removed the catchall from my app start routeconfig

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "product",
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "product",
            //    url: "{product}/{*catchall}",
            //    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index"});

              routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }) ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to load an angular app into a container of your MVC application? i.e. the Index is not an angular app but the partial will be child angular app? Or is this an angular app with MVC backend and the Index page was always configured for angular?

Comment: The angular app has an mvc backend. So the mvc will provide data, and a top level view for each controller. But anything after the Product/ angular route should take over and display partial html in ng view

Comment: Doesn't removing the CATCH ALL make MVC do the work (rather than Angular)?

Comment: From what I remember, no it did not help. I finally decided to go down the webapi and angular route and ditch asp.net mvc and angular

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the partialview as a normal view, so your Index page is never used. A partial view is supposed to be a part of a view (hence the partial).

If you create a normal Index action that returns the default view (`return view()`), you can add `@Html.Partial("_Test")` to your index.cshtml file to load the partial there.

Alternatively, you could check out child actions to return a part of the page if you want to use an action for a partial. For example, create the static part of the page in the normal Index, and place a child-action or partial to put any dynamic bits in. If that doesn't work out, perhaps you can first get your Angular code working in a regular Index page and then cut it into partials. I think you're mixing up a few things by trying several new things at the same time.

Comment: This did return the partial view, but i want this view to return after clicking the href. Otherwise i will have many partial views displayed on this single index page.